# javascript removing item from an array, splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, splice

I'm making a small appwith localstaorage (not implemented yet): you type a note int the text area and it is display in a list

the note are stacked in an object called notes (for localstorage in the future);

But my problem is : I can add a note, but when I try  to remove on of them, I have to remove my li and the related note object in the 'notes' array, so i decided to use splice method, but it works in a strange way...

when i click 'close', it works fine one or two times but at a moment the array stays with one or two object in it...

I tried different ways to solve the problem but without success...

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h8hg6/1/

thanks for your help

Comment: post the relevant code as well as the link to it

Comment: functionally it seems to work fine using your fiddle. I'm unclear as to the actual issue.

Comment: your `note` variable in `addNoteToPage` is an implicit global, not sure if it's related to the problem or not.

Comment: i've edited my question with an online example to make the issue clearer... I hope... You can check the console for it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modifications to your fiddle that I think solve the problem. Essentially you were using `.splice` incorrectly, and your Array was falling out of sync with your note elements. I've replaced your array with an numeric-based object because it is much easier to deal with. Here are some of the relevant changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/h8hg6/2/

```
var notes = {}; // notes is now an object instead of an array
// snip

var number = jQuery(this).parents('li').data('number');
delete notes[number]; // this is how you remove properties from an object

// snip
var note = {
    color: color,
    text: text
};

notes[i] = note; // add this object as a property of the notes object
i++;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I put 5 note and i close them, the array is never empty, there are at least two items...

Comment: @user1521149 according to the console in chrome, it's working perfectly.

Comment: I'm still seeing the object after i close the note :-/

Comment: @user1521149 that's because the `console.log` statements are before the `delete` statement.

Comment: mm i removed the console.log and I have still my array with at least one object

Comment: ok it works, I have to increment my i AFTER the addnote function launch ^^ thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your call to `splice` uses the value of the `queue` variable to determine the index of the element that will be removed in the `notes` array. Right here:

```
notes.splice(queue, 1);
```

Since the `queue` value is always increasing (right here):

```
 function addNoteToPage(){
    i++;
    ...
    jQuery('ul#notes li:first').before('<li  data-queue="'+ i +'">'+ note.text +' <a href=""#>CLOSE</a>
```

You hit a moment where you call splice on an non-existing index of the `notes` array and  nothing is removed as a result. Basically, you end up with an out-of-sync `notes` array.

You need to make sure that the value of the `data-queue` attribute coincides with the real index of the element in the `notes` array so that your call to `splice(queue,1)` always succeeds and removes the appropriate array element.

With that said, if above answer works for you, I'd go with that one. I just wanted to give you more insight on what was going on...

Comment: thansk a lot, yes i've seen my mistake 2 minutes ago, so i try another way: i stock the text of the note and compare it with note.text. It works but there is others issues... if I enter the 5 same note, the behaviour is stange :-/ http://jsfiddle.net/h8hg6/2/